# Grafana Legend format :9100 removal

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

I have ":9100" showing up at the end of my metrics. I am using a prometheus datasource with my company and can't change it. Has anyone figured out how to remove this? I was thinking maybe templates or regex but I haven't been successful yet.

Configuration:

Legend Format = {{hostname}}

Result = myhostname.mydomain.com:9100

Answer (score 44):

As far as I know, currently it is not possible to format the legend in Grafana (there is an open PR for it), however as you are using Prometheus, you can use its `label_replace()` function, eg.:

```
label_replace(my_vector, "short_hostname", "$1", "hostname", "(.*):.*")
```

This should give you:

```
Legend Format = {{short_hostname}}

Result = myhostname.mydomain.com
```

[See the docs here - label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace)

Comment: Where would I type this?  I tried in the Legend Format edit box, and I tried defining a variable.  I want to do this too, but I can't figure out from your comment how.  Thanks.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my above question . The label_replace() function wraps the original PromQL query, which is referred to as "my_vector" here.  This example translates the "hostname" variable and creates a new one called "short_hostname".  Then in the Legend Format, you can specify "{{short_hostname}}" to get the translated value, without the ":9100".  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In Grafana 8.0, there is Transform menu that can be used to remove text. I hope it is still relevant to this question.

On Dashboard, select the panel >  Edit. There are 3 tabs below chart, one of them is Transform. Select Transform > Add Transformation > Rename by Regex, fill the form with these values:

- Match: ***":9100"*** (without quotes)
- Replace: keep it empty

Please refer to the [link](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/apply-transformations/) for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are statically mentioning targets in the Prometheus config file as follows:

```
- job_name: "node_exporter"
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100']
```

In that case, if you see the `{{instance_name}}` in grafana, it will give you the same as your target name `['localhost:9100']`. This is because it uses the `static_configs` to avail labels for your metrics.

In order to remove the `:9100` from the labels, you can use service discovery to recognize targets.

For example: `ec2_sd_config` where the labels will be availed from labels mentioned in AWS EC2 dashboard, `file_sd_config` where you can provide the targets and their labels in json or yaml format, etc.

Please refer to the [link](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) for detailed information.

Hope this helps!