# Regex to capture the IP or hostname from a list having a mix of IP and hostname

Tags: regex, hostname, grafana-variable

For my situation, I need to extract the IP address or the hostname from the list. For example, suppose this is the list

> d-bns-teaut-12.corporate.net:9100,
> 10.212.142.61:9100,
> d-bns-teaut-23.corporate.net:9100,
> 10.212.142.87:9100,
> d-bns-teaut-25.corporate.net:9100,
> 10.212.142.98:9100

I need to extract

> d-bns-teaut-12,10.212.142.61,d-bns-teaut-23,10.212.142.87,d-bns-teaut-25 and 10.212.142.98

So far I know how to extract either the IP or hostname, but not both with a regex at the same time.

I tried with the expression `/([a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+)/` and with that I am able to extract the IP and if I add anymore regex patter to extract the `.corporate.net`, I do not get the IP in the results.

Comment: do you have IPv6 addresses? are all the addresses exclusively a valid hostname or IP or are there other values? in such a case, try an IP parser (rejected addresses are a hostname) or if there are no IPv6 addresses and exclusivity, just checking for any letter (must exist in TLD, while a normal IPv4 address cannot contain letters) is sufficient

Comment: Does `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[^.]+)` work? Also, try `^([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[^.]+)`  and `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[^.]+).*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grafana Legend format :9100 removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293510/grafana-legend-format-9100-removal)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Thanks Wiktor. `([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[^.]+)` worked perfectly for my use case. Now it extracts all the IP and also the hostname from the list. Thanks again

Comment: @ti7 : I do not have IPv6 address and also your suggested question is not what I wanted. That answers my question only partially. I really appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}|[^.]+)
```

The pattern is a *capturing group* (`(...)`) that matches either

- `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}` - one, two or three digits and three other occurrences of `.` and one, two or three digits
- `|` - or
- `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than `.` char.